# React Router Dom prevents whole App from rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

For some reason when I call the BrowserRouter inside my App() function, the whole App is prevented from being rendered. If I comment out the  lines, the App works. I am a complete new to React. Is there something I am doing wrong?

index.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App'

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>:S</h1>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <h1>:)</h1>
            </BrowserRouter>
            <h1>:(</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
export default App;
```

I thought that even if there was something wrong with BrowserRouter at least the first h1 tag would render, but no. The whole function just disappears and the page is blank.

What should I do?

EDIT: Browser console throws this error

```
react.development.js:1476 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (bundle.js:44878:17)
    at useRef (bundle.js:44918:24)
    at BrowserRouter (bundle.js:42102:65)
    at renderWithHooks (bundle.js:22138:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (bundle.js:24900:17)
    at beginWork (bundle.js:26099:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (bundle.js:11088:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:11137:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:11197:35)
    at beginWork$1 (bundle.js:30939:11)
react-dom.development.js:20085 The above error occurred in the <BrowserRouter> component:

    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42098:5)
    at div
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:20085
bootstrap:27 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (bundle.js:44878:17)
    at useRef (bundle.js:44918:24)
    at BrowserRouter (bundle.js:42102:65)
    at renderWithHooks (bundle.js:22138:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (bundle.js:24900:17)
    at beginWork (bundle.js:26099:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (bundle.js:11088:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:11137:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:11197:35)
    at beginWork$1 (bundle.js:30939:11)
```

Comment: Code runs without issue here in this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-burnell-0d7gbk?file=/src/App.js:133-183). I don't see any issue with it. Try restarting your development server. Are there any errors/warnings in your browser's devtools console?

Comment: What version of React Router Dom are you using? Blank screens occur when an error occurs. Open the browser console (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`J`) and paste the error (if any) in your question.

Comment: Does this error occur *even after* killing and restarting your development server? Is there more to your code than what you've shared? Can you share your package.json file?

Comment: Thanks. I just did. I installed react by 'npx create-react-app' so I did not touch the ReactDOM. How can I check if I have more than one copy of react installed?

Comment: What version of React Router Dom are you using?

Comment: 6.2.1 which is the latest

Comment: Well, I think I found the issue. I am running the react app inside a 'client' folder within the same project as the server code. For some reason, I installed the react-router-dom in the upper folder instead of the 'client' folder.

Comment: I see. Glad you got it sorted out. I voted to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I had wrongly installed react-router-dom in the parent directory of the project (which hosts the server) instead of the client subfolder (where react lives).